# Disable jettys debug output in (html)Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, logging, jetty

i use Jetty (v.6.1.25) in a Unit Test(more specific: htmlUnit) to test Servlets,Filters and something like.
And I don't will see all the debug output in console.
I've found something like:

```
System.setProperty("org.mortbay.log.DEBUG","false");
```

..but it doesn't work for me.
Is there a simple way to say: "be quiet"? (Of course errors i must see :) )

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line to hide the debug output:

```
java -jar start.jar etc/jetty-logging.xml
```

and route it to a rolling log file.

**References**

- [Jetty Logging](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Logging)